# how to correctly format a csv file for import in magento

Tags: error, import, csv

I am currently trying to import products from a supplier however I get multiple errors which I assume have to do with the formatting of the csv file I am trying to import.
the column headers in the csv file are as follows.

```
    Name,SKU,UPC,Description,Weight,"Dimensions(length x width x eight)",Price,MAP
```

and the content is as follows

```
       "Product Name",SKGK,"6 16983 31439 5","inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam
 voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
 consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
 Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
 consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
 incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut
 enim ad ",10,"15"" x 12"" x 6""",27.2,38.99
```

however I get multiple different errors, how would I format this correctly so that I can import data into magento?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to create a product in magento , then go to System >> import/Export >> Dataflow Profile menu. Export a CSV from there & then use it as sample.

Comment: would I have to include all of the attributes in the csv file or could I just include the csv file above with corrected values

Comment: you have to add all required attributes. safe to go with all attributes.

Comment: Dataflow is deprecated. And slow.